# Double Hashing and Variations for Bloom Filters

Tags: data-structures, hash, hash-tables, bloom-filters

I am reading a few papers on Bloom Filters – [Bloom Filters in Probabilistic Verification](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/pete/pub/bloom-filters-verification.pdf) (Dillinger and Manolios) suggests the following allocations for double and triple hashing respectively

> $$\begin{align*}
> f[i] &= a(δ) + ib(δ)\pmod{m}\\
> f[i] &= a(δ) + ib(δ) + (c(δ)(i)(i − 1))/2 \pmod{m}
> \end{align*}$$

[Less Hashing Same Performance: Building A Better Bloom Filter](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~michaelm/postscripts/rsa2008.pdf) (Kirsch and Mitzenmacher) references the former one and suggests similar double hash function with an implementation difference where a double hash instead gives a slot in $g _i$th subarray:

> $ g_i(x) = h_1 (x)+ih_2 (x)\pmod{p}$, where $h_1(x)$ and $h_2(x)$ are two
>   independent, uniform random hash functions on the universe with range
>   ${0, \dots , p − 1}$, and throughout we
>   assume that $i$ ranges from $0$ to $k − 1$.

It would seem that will mean the memory footprint should be $kp$ – do I understand this correctly?
Secondly the paper states that:

> The advantage of our simplified setting is that for any two elements
>   x, y ∈ U, exactly one of the following three cases occurs:
>
> - $g_i (x) \neq g_i (y)$ for all $i$, or
> - $g_i (x) = g_i (y)$ for exactly one $i$, or
> - $g_i (x) = g_i (y)$ for all $i$.

As for as I understand for the above conditions to be fulfilled (*I missed this part on my first look through it*) - 
The following specifications must be observed:

> $h_1, h_2$ are two independent, uniform random hash functions on the
>   universe with range $0, 1, 2, . . . , p − 1$.

Otherwise partial collisions would occur when $(h_2(x) - h_2(y))*n = m$ (if $m$ is not prime) and at $(h_2(x) - h_2(y)) = p*n$ when the hash function range is at least $2p$.

The standard estimate for minimizing false positivity in a bloom filter is $k = \frac{m}{n}\ ln 2$ - since a set of $k_i$ subarrays can be treated as a continuous space in memory: with each $k$th hash being allocated within the range $ip$ - $(i+1)p$ for the $i$th subarray of size $p$) - the same estimate (I think) should be applicable where $p \approx m/k$.

But usually the hash functions are limited by a few choices which perform optimally given a CPU architecture, this would appear to leave the options severely constrained in the choice of $p$ specifically by the yield of the hash function (32 bits, 64 bits, 128 bits etc.) which dictate that an optimal $p$ is the nearest prime $<$ the range of the hash function.

Given those constraints it would seem like this scheme is optimized for filters of a very specific size - although I was under the general impression that if a good approximation of number of items that need to be stored is known that hash tables demonstrate better performance?

Comment: You have been editing this a lot. While I always appreciate users improving their posts, note that pushing out a huge number of (minor) edits presents some problems; for one thing, you keep pushing your question to the top of the question list. I recommend you prepare your posts more carefully (let them sit for some days!), and/or collect edits until you have a bigger edit together. (See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/754/), [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/669) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/729)).

Comment: @Raphael Thanks for the criticism, I'll keep the edits together next time.